Why vq-vae sometimes struggles with homogenous background?
While training i noticed this problem
pic1

pic2

pic3

pic4


it probably depends on too many factors to answer you... architecture, optimization, loss, normalization

so, you mean that there is no intuitive explanation?

I only mean that i hard to give you an educated guess / answer without many more information
